# Is there a way to calculate the area of a PNG image over a transparent background?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, png

Say, you have a canvas size of 10"x10" in Photoshop.

Then, you have an image on that canvas (with a transparent background).  Well, if you imagine the entire canvas being taken up, the total area would be 100 square inches (10x10).  But, say you have an image inside this canvas.  Is there a way in Photoshop, Illustrator, whatever, to figure out how much area is taken up by this image, given the canvas size?

Comment: It's pretty easy to do with Javascript, but perhaps outside the scope of this site ... I might post something later.

Comment: FYI, generally this is what is called a "bounding box" or "minimum bounding rectangle." IIRC Photoshop's locked default base layer has the canvas extents as its bounding box (at least based on Photoshop's estimated uncompressed file size), but subsequent layers may vary and can have a bounding box larger than the canvas.

Comment: Do you need rectangular area or the image may have 'holes' that should be subtracted from bounding box? If latter, what level of precision do you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I do it:

Inside Photoshop, make a selection and make a path from selection.

Copy that path and paste it in Illustrator.

Use the script [GetShapeArea](https://gist.github.com/bryanbuchanan/11387501) to calculate the area.

Note: In the image below I altered the code to show just cm². But the code has in² and cm².

[image]

Comment: PERFECT!  This works!! Thank you